# What are some resources for Linux developers learning OpenAL Effects Extension (EFX)?

Tags: c++, linux, openal

What are some resources for Linux developers learning OpenAL Effects Extension (EFX)? Creative's site and google did not seem to offer much in the way of documentation or tutorials.  Any pointers to references are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only kind of good source that I know is the *"Effects Extension Guide"* which comes as a PDF with the SDK (no official documentation is available on the internet otherwise, many attempts to find something have been futile, you also cannot download the Effects Extension Guide separately, it's only available with the SDK).

The SDK also comes with some mildly helpful EFX examples about how to query and initialize EFX, and a reverb example (which cynically needs OpenAL Soft on my computer, since it doesn't run properly with the Creative implementation).

While rather detailled, the Effects Extension Guide is unluckily (at least partly) written in a way that is not immediately comprehensive for someone not being an audio engineer.

Other than that, there exist about half a dozen master thesis papers (some in German) which contain a lot of blah blah but don't tell you much, and there are a few very basic usage examples on the net, such as [this one](http://www.opentk.com/node/714).

Most of it, you'll sadly have figure yourself from the Effects Extension Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That's the feeling I was getting regarding the SDK.